# C# syntax highlighting broken on SO?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008600/get-program-icons/6008639#6008639), comments in C# code have the same color as normal code. In the preview the highlighting is correct, but not on the submitted answer. Looks like a bug...

Comment: The preview probably does not take the tags into account, so using the default which is "global" and can identify most languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the question is tagged as `vb.net`, it doesn't automatically apply C# code formatting. You can override this by adding a special comment before the code block that specifies the highlighting language:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
```

Comment: ah, didn't know that... thanks!

Comment: I always thought it needs to be `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` glad to see there's little shortcut. :)